# Converting to Uppercase - Python

Tags: python

How would I get this to work? I'm trying to define a function that returns the string, which is a copy of the parameter, but where all of the upper case ASCII letters have been converted to lower case ASCII letters. I don't want to use any other built in functions such as .upper() etc. or dictionary.

```
ASCII_LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ASCII_UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
DECIMAL_DIGITS = "0123456789"

def to_lower(a_string):
    if not a_string:
        return False
    for i in a_string:
        if not (i in ASCII_LOWERCASE or i in ASCII_UPPERCASE):
            return False
        if i in ASCII_LOWERCASE or i in ASCII_UPPERCASE:           
            for i in ASCII_UPPERCASE:            
                return ASCII_LOWERCASE

y=to_lower("ABCabc")
print(y)
```

Prints Out: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Comment: OK! Do you have a question?

Comment: Why not?  `str.lower()` and `str.upper()` are faster and support unicode too :D

Comment: I'm trying to do this without using built in functions @Iguananaut

Comment: "I'm trying to do this without using built in functions" **Why?**

Comment: By the way, [assignment and the `in` operator boil down to using built in functions.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html)

Comment: Oh, and in Python 3.x, `print` is a built in function.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a dictionary of your letters then based on its item you can convert your string with the following function  :

```
>>> d=(dict(zip(ASCII_UPPERCASE,ASCII_LOWERCASE)))
>>> def to_lower(a_string):
...      return ''.join(d[i] if i in d else i for i in a_string)
... 
>>> to_lower("A")
'a'
>>> to_lower("Aa23BC")
'aa23bc'
```

Comment: How would I do this without a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the reason your code doesn't work is because when you execute a `return` statement in the middle of a loop, the function exits and no further looping or processing within it will occur.

Here are several working versions that all do what you want in essentially the same way, by using look-up tables. I'm including them all since it's unclear to me exactly what all the artificial restrictions there are on what built-ins you're allowed to use.

Note that there's only one `return` statement at the very end of each version of the function.

```
# note these two are same as string.ascii_lowercase and string.ascii_uppercase
ASCII_LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ASCII_UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

def to_lower(a_string):
    chars = []
    for char in a_string:
        if char in ASCII_UPPERCASE:
            chars.append(ASCII_LOWERCASE[ord(char)-ord('A')])
        else:
            chars.append(char)
    return ''.join(chars)

y=to_lower("ABC-123.abc")
print(y)  # --> abc-123.abc
```

This next version manually creates a single translation table from the other two and then manually applies it to each character of the string.

```
TRANSLATE_TABLE = [ASCII_LOWERCASE[v-ord('A')] if chr(v) in ASCII_UPPERCASE else
                   chr(v) for v in range(256)]

def to_lower(a_string):
    return ''.join(TRANSLATE_TABLE[ord(char)] for char in a_string)

y=to_lower("ABC-123.abc")
print(y)  # --> abc-123.abc
```

This final version uses the static string method `maketrans()` to build the translation table and then applies it with the `translate()` method of string object argument to do any and all replacements needed in one call. It's the most efficient and shortest.

```
TRANSLATE_TABLE = ''.maketrans(ASCII_UPPERCASE, ASCII_LOWERCASE)

def to_lower(a_string):
    return a_string.translate(TRANSLATE_TABLE)

y=to_lower("ABC-123.abc")
print(y)  # --> abc-123.abc
```